# how to create the address of litecoin using pycoin library?

Tags: python, blockchain, bitcoin

I have generate the address of bitcoin using python script. How to generate the address of Litecoin.

Here is my code to generate bitcoin address

```
import hashlib
from pycoin import ecdsa, encoding
import os
import codecs
for i in range(10):
    rand = codecs.encode(os.urandom(32), 'hex').decode()
    secret_exponent= int('0x'+rand, 0)
    print ('WIF: ' + encoding.secret_exponent_to_wif(secret_exponent, compressed=False))
    public_pair = ecdsa.public_pair_for_secret_exponent(ecdsa.secp256k1.generator_secp256k1, secret_exponent)
    hash160 = encoding.public_pair_to_hash160_sec(public_pair, compressed=True)
    print('Bitcoin address: %s' % encoding.hash160_sec_to_bitcoin_address(hash160))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in this function     secret_exponent_to_wif

```
def secret_exponent_to_wif(se, compressed):
    blob = to_bytes_32(se)
    if compressed:
        blob += b'\01'
    return BitcoinMainnet.ui.wif_for_blob(blob)
```

Here it uses BitcoinMainnet to generate Bitcoin address.You just use LitecoinMannet to generate Litecoin address . It is already there in pycoin.coins.litecoin library. By changing the corresponding network values you can generate address of any crypto key